# recursion in ocaml nested lists

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am new to Ocaml and am writing code to substitute elements in nested Ocaml lists. My code is as follows:

```
type 'a sexp = S of 'a | L of 'a sexp list
```

My substitution function(it replaces all occurrences of element a with b in nested lists) is as follows:

```
let rec subst a b list = 
  match list with
  | [] -> list
  | S s :: t -> 
      if s = a then (S b) :: (subst a b t) 
      else (S s) :: (subst a b t)
  | L l :: t -> (subst a b l) :: (subst a b t)
```

Despite multiple attempts(for nearly 6 hours), I have not been able to compile this code.. Please help!

Comment: Try substituting the last line with `|L l :: t -> L (subst a b l) :: (subst a b t) `.

Comment: @Shredderoy It solved my problem but please do explain it to me as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can I suggest to first write a function `subst` of type `'a -> 'a -> 'a sexp -> 'a sexp` instead? It would read

```
let subst x y sexp =
  let rec visit = function
    | S z -> S (if z = x then y else z)
    | L sexps -> L (List.map visit sexps)
  in
  visit sexp
```

and arguably nicely and idiomatically captures the idea of recursing over an `sexp`.

Now, to obtain a function to operate on lists rather than single `sexp`s, you can easily define a function `subst_list` of type `'a -> 'a -> 'a sexp list -> 'a sexp list`:

```
let subst_list x y sexps = List.map (subst x y) sexps
```

---

Even nicer is to abstract away from substitution and have a more generally applicable function `map` of type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a sexp -> 'b sexp` for performing structure-preserving mappings of `sexp`s:

```
let map f sexp =
  let rec visit = function
    | S x -> S (f x)
    | L sexps -> L (List.map visit sexps)
  in
  visit sexp
```

And then define `subst` in terms of `map` and `subst_list`, as before, in terms of `subst`:

```
let subst x y sexp = map (fun z -> if z = x then y else z) sexp
let subst_list x y sexps = List.map (subst x y) sexps
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: using an F# compiler here; I don't have an OCaml compiler on this computer.

The last line of your `subst` function has an error:  It should be as follows:

```
| L l :: t -> L (subst a b l) :: (subst a b t)
```

So the complete code would look like this:

```
type 'a Sexp =
    | S of 'a
    | L of 'a Sexp list

let rec subst (a) (b) (lst : 'a Sexp list) =
    match lst with
    | [] -> lst
    | S s :: t -> if s = a then (S b) :: (subst a b t) else (S s) :: (subst a b t)
    | L l :: t -> L (subst a b l) :: (subst a b t)

let test () =
    let (lst : int Sexp list) = [S 1; L [S 2; L [S 3]; S 4]; S 5]
    let a = 2
    let b = 3
    subst a b lst
```

The output of `test()` is

```
[S 1; L [S 3; L [S 3]; S 4]; S 5]
```

The reason is that your function `subst` returns a `'a Sexp list`.  If you omit the `L` constructor from the last line, then `subst a b l` is of type `'a Sexp list`, which you are attempting to cons with another list of type `'a Sexp list`.  This does not work.

Nor was this your intention, since you wanted to end up with an entity of type `'a Sexp list`, which means you must cons an element of type `'a Sexp` with a list of type `'a Sexp list`.  By specifying the `L` constructor, you are creating an element of type `'a Sexp list`, which you can now cons with the rest of the list.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your function `subst` is supposed to return something of type `'a sexp list`. That's what the first and second match cases return.

In the third match case, then, your returned value is:

```
(subst a b l) :: (subst a b t)
```

Since your function returns `'a sexp list`, this type doesn't make a lot of sense. The head of the list is of type `'a sexp list` and the tail of the list is *also* of type `'a sexp list`. It's very difficult to come up with any lists that have this kind of structure. I think what you want is for the head of the list to be of type `'a sexp`.

If you want the head of the list to be of type `'a sexp`, you need some way of packaging up a list of things into a single '`a sexp`. If this isn't enough of a hint, look at your `L` constructor. That's exactly what it does.

Comment: Did you mean `a sexp list` instead of `a subst list` in the last two paragraphs?

Comment: Whoops, I will fix. Thanks.